# Translate & to %20%26%20

Tags: linux, bash

I know I can translate upper to lower case letters by

```
echo 'linux' | tr "a-z" "A-Z"
```

how would I translate or replace an occurrence of & with %20%26%20. Maybe something like this

```
echo '&' | tr "&" "%20%26%20"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/&/%20%26%20/g' inputfile
```

will edit the file in place.

Comment: @hfranco: On my system, the ampersand doesn't need to be escaped on the left side.

Comment: @hfranco. Yeah, mine is fine also.

Answer (score 2):

you can just use the shell.

```
$ var="&test"
$ echo ${var//&/%20%26%20}
%20%26%20test
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `tr` command does not work is that `tr` treats it's 2 arguments, not as arbitrary strings, but as lists. `tr` finds "&" in the string; it's the first element in the first argument; it gets replaced by the corresponding first element in the second argument.

From the [man page](http://bama.ua.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?tr):

> When the -d option is not specified:
>
> ```
>     o  Each input character found in the array  specified  by
>        string1 is replaced by the character in the same rela-
>        tive position in the array specified by string2.  When
>        the array specified by string2 is shorter that the one
>        specified by string1, the results are unspecified.
> ```

The `sed` and `bash` solutions offered are what you want.